# Storyboard doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'PlannerViewController'

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I attached a `PlannerViewController` to my `Main.storyboard`. When I build and run the app, I get the following error :

```
Storyboard (<NSStoryboard: 0x608000001790>) doesn't contain a controller with identifier 'PlannerViewController'
```

In Main.storyboard, I did set `PlannerViewController` as the custom class and storyboard ID. Here's the code in PlannerViewController.swift :

```
import Cocoa

class PlannerViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

}


extension PlannerViewController {
    // MARK: Storyboard instantiation
    static func freshController() -> PlannerViewController {

        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        guard let viewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "PlannerViewController") as? PlannerViewController else {
        fatalError("Why cant i find QuotesViewController? - Check Main.storyboard")
        }
        return viewcontroller

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error ?

Please note that I'm using Swift 3, and that I'm new to Swift.

Thanks.

EDIT : By the way, I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/450-menus-and-popovers-in-menu-bar-apps-for-macos#toc-anchor-004) to develop a menu bar app.

Comment: Do you add an identifier "PlannerViewController" to view controller on storyboard?

Comment: When I add `let identifier = NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "QuotesViewController")` I get this error : `NSStoryboard has no member 'SceneIdentifier'`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add id `PlannerViewController` here [image]